# Android : how to implement PullToRefreshListView in proper way

Tags: android, performance

i am new to Android and currently start learning how to implement PullToRefreshListview by using this library of chrisbanes. can you guys please explain to me, where should i put my code to call API for getting data, and which part should i set the(ImageBitmap) after i get the data (image URL) from API. as i know, we should do something in background to avoid the UI freeze when loading Image to UI, but i am not sure. Please help.

The following is the sample code from the library:
please explain to me what should i do in GetDataTask and onPostExecute. In the case like loading image.

```
@Override
public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
    // Do work to refresh the list here.
    new GetDataTask().execute();
}

private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Simulates a background job.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        return mStrings;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        mListItems.addFirst("Added after refresh...");
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
        mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Sorry for the newbie question, i jsust want to confirm it in order to follow the standard. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your GetDataTask in a separated class with a Listener. This is an example of a listener you can have:

```
public abstract class RemoteCallListener implements IRemoteCallListener {

@Override
public abstract void onString(String s); //String is just an example.

@Override
public abstract void onError(Exception e);
}
```

You should give the listener to your constructor if your async task.

```
private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

RemoteCallListener listener;
public GetDataTask(){

}

public GetDataTask(RemoteCallListener listener){
this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Simulates a background job.
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    return mStrings;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
listener.onString(result);
    // mListItems.addFirst("Added after refresh...");
    // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
    // mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

To make an instance of the call you should do something like

```
 GetDataTask task = new GetDataTask(yourlistener);
 task.execute("your link");
```

And in your 'controller'class you should make an instance of RemoteCallListener and when onString is called:

```
   mListItems.addFirst("Added after refresh...");
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
    mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();
```

You can also freeze the UI by the Dialogs class from android. An example is given here:

```
public final static ProgressDialog showLoading(Context c, String title,
        String message, boolean indeterminate) {
    ProgressDialog p = new ProgressDialog(c);
    p.setTitle(title);
    p.setMessage(message);
    p.setCancelable(false);
    p.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);
    if (!indeterminate) {
        // p.setProgressDrawable( c.getResources().getDrawable(
        // R.drawable.progress ) );
        p.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        p.setProgress(0);
        p.setMax(100);
    }
    p.show();
    return p;
}
```

But dont forget to close your Dialog!

You can contact me anytime if you have further questions

Answer (score 0):

GetDataTask is used to call your webservice again to get the new list items. These things should be done in doInBackground. Once you get the new list item need to set the new adapter for your listview in onPostExecute.